# Problem with wp_enqueue_script

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to use wp_enqueue_script on my theme, to insert 3 javascript files on my page.

```
function mr_forms() {

            wp_register_script('validate-jquery',  get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/js/jquery.validate.min.js', array('jquery'),FALSE,TRUE);
            wp_enqueue_script('validate-jquery');
            wp_register_script('aditional-methods', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/js/additional-methods.min.js', array('jquery','validate'),FALSE,TRUE);
            wp_enqueue_script('aditional-methods');
            wp_register_script('messages-ptbr', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/js/messages_ptbr.js', array('jquery','validate'),FALSE,TRUE);
            wp_enqueue_script('messages-ptbr');
            wp_register_script('forms', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/js/forms.js', array('jquery', 'maskedinput'), FALSE, TRUE);
            wp_enqueue_script('forms');
        }

        add_action('init', 'mr_forms');
```

But only the last javascript, "forms.js" is being inserted on my page, the others arent, does anyone know what might be happening ? and the other doesnt matter...

Comment: Can you confirm jQuery is being loaded?

Comment: It must be if forms.js is loading - I'm certain it'll be that validate is being required, rather than validate-jquery

Answer (score 1):

Have you named validate incorrectly in the other register scripts? Should be **validate-jquery** instead of **validate**?

```
function mr_forms() {

        wp_register_script('validate-jquery',  get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/js/jquery.validate.min.js', array('jquery'),FALSE,TRUE);
        wp_enqueue_script('validate-jquery');
        wp_register_script('aditional-methods', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/js/additional-methods.min.js', array('jquery','validate-jquery'),FALSE,TRUE);
        wp_enqueue_script('aditional-methods');

wp_register_script('messages-ptbr', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/js/messages_ptbr.js', array('jquery','validate-jquery'),FALSE,TRUE);

        wp_enqueue_script('messages-ptbr');
        wp_register_script('forms', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/js/forms.js', array('jquery', 'maskedinput'), FALSE, TRUE);
        wp_enqueue_script('forms');
    }

    add_action('init', 'mr_forms');
```

Comment: thats not the problem..... I changed from "validate" to "validate-jquery" just to test if it was a name problem...... that's still not the problem but thx for trying... I can even remove the dependencies and it still doesn't load the files...

Comment: Are you looking in the footer, or in the head?